# Error Code 500 cannot read properties of null (reading 'binding')

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to rebuild and old project and this is my updated package.json

```
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "postinstall": "npx jetify",
    "extractLangs": "react-gettext-parser --output messages.pot 'src/**/*.js'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^6.3.1",
    "axios": "0.24.0",
    "base-64": "1.0.0",
    "date-fns": "2.27.0",
    "gettext.js": "git+https://github.com/freiserg/gettext.js.git",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "8.4.8",
    "react-native-eject": "0.1.2",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "0.12.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.5",
    "react-native-navigation": "7.24.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.3.0",
    "react-native-swipeout": "2.3.6",
    "react-native-swiper": "1.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "9.0.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "7.2.6",
    "redux": "4.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.4.1",
    "shitty-qs": "1.0.1",
    "tcomb-form-native": "0.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "27.4.5",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.6",
    "eslint": "8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.27.1",
    "jest": "27.4.5",
    "jetifier": "2.0.0",
    "nock": "13.2.1",
    "react-gettext-parser": "1.16.0",
    "react-native-mock": "0.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.4"
```

I have deleted both android and ios folder and regenerated them using react-native eject. Everything was smooth until I run react-native run-android I get this respond

[image]

My current .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the culprit and it turns out to be babel-preset-react-native which has been depreciated. So I replaced it with metro-react-native-babel-preset, which solves most of the problem.

Also changed  .babelrc to

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```